# Retrieve list items using Search API

Tags: javascript, search-results, search-api

My requirement is to retrieve list items using search API instead of rest API.
I have used a content type for the list but I am unable to retrieve the items in the List.This is due to the incorrect I think.

```
url:/sites/mysite/_api/search/query?querytext='(contenttype:Company)'&sourceid='D94AD30B-63E6-4B54-A3D2-258A590E3EB6'&selectproperties='Title,CompanyDescriptionOWSMTXT'
```

I used the above url and unable to get the first 30 items.Please help!
thanks in advance

Comment: here's how to use SharePoint search API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163876.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to use the ContentTypeId: instead of the ContentType Name like this:

```
https://site.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='ContentTypeId:0x01005FC5182DF0BF554287F15C4D8B798E6*'
```

if the content type is used in other lists, then it is better to add the path of the targeted list and your query will look like this:

```
https://site.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='ContentTypeId:0x01005FC5182DF0BF554287F15C4D8B798E6*+Path:https://paratekpharma.sharepoint.com/site/Lists/listname'
```

You can get the ID of your content type using the following steps:

- Navigate to https://site.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/mngctype.aspx
- Locate the content type of the list
- Hover over the content type and copy the id after ManageContentType.aspx

for example: ManageContentType.aspx?ctype=`0x01005FC5182DF0BF554287F15C4D8B798E60`

Note: I removed the last 0 from the content type and added a * instead

Comment: what can we do for cross domain??